# Component not re rendering when setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, rerender

I know there is another question similar to this which needs to make component re render when a list is changed but in my situation I need to trigger a re render when changing a string. I wanted to know how I could do this without putting it into a list and spreading it into a new list.

I'm trying to re render TVChartContainer with new data when the `symbol` changes. `updateChart` is the function that runs to update `symbol` and it is told to run by the `useEffect` right below it.

```
const IndustryCharts = () => {
    const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState('TECHNOLOGY');
    const [pickedCard, setPickedCard] = useState(null);
    const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(industryListData.industryList.map(() => 'tilebox-one'));
    // console.log(industryListData.industryList);

    const pickACard = (index) => {
        setSelectedCard(index);
        // console.log(selectedCard + index);
    };

    const cardNumber = (index) => {
        const holdSelectedCard = industryListData.industryList.map(() => 'tilebox-one');
        holdSelectedCard[index] = 'tilebox-two tilebox-one';
        setSelectedCard(holdSelectedCard);
        // console.log('it worked', holdSelectedCard);
    };

    const updateChart = () => {
        let selectedIndex = 0;
        selectedCard.forEach((theCard, cardIndex) => {
            if (theCard === 'tilebox-two tilebox-one') {
                selectedIndex = cardIndex;
                setSymbol(industryListData.industryList[cardIndex].Industry);
            }
        });
        // props.history.push(allPaths[selectedIndex]);
        console.log(symbol);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        updateChart();
    }, [selectedCard]);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col xl={3} lg={4}>
                    <SimpleBar style={{ maxHeight: '900px', width: '100%' }}>
                        {industryListData.industryList.map((industryListItem, index) => (
                            <IndustryCards
                                pickedCard={pickedCard}
                                setPickedCard={setPickedCard}
                                key={industryListItem.Industry + selectedCard[index]}
                                {...industryListItem}
                                listItem={industryListItem}
                                onClick={() => {
                                    pickACard(index);
                                }}
                                changeCard={cardNumber}
                                currentCard={selectedCard[index]}
                                index={index}
                                selectedCard={selectedCard}
                                setSelectedCard={setSelectedCard}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </SimpleBar>
                </Col>
                <Col xl={9} lg={8}>
                    <TVChartContainer style={{ maxHeight: '800px', width: '80%' }} symbol={symbol} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: `useEffect` second argument should be an array of dependencies `[selectedCard]`. btw, where do you update `selectedCard`? I don't see you calling `setSelectedCard` at your code

Comment: Just edited to add full code. I took out some of the functions I didn't think were important to this issue thinking it would make it easier to see. Updated selectedCard to an array, but it didn't help

Comment: what each `theCard` prints once `updatedCard` triggers?  I see you `selectedCard` is at first an array but it can change to an index (with `pickACard` method). I would say at first `selectedCard` is not truthy about what it really is. I would consider to set `selectCard` only a key id.